# How to do Wordpress dev/prod development with the database?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to reason through the best way to accomplish this. If you have two environments for the same site (a *dev* and a *prod* environment each respectively).

If each of these sites has its own database (*devdb* and *proddb*), and you're developing new pages etc on the dev site and database.

What is the typical way to transfer the changes in the dev database to the prod database? Is there any native way (or plugin) to handle this in WordPress?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In case you have CI/CD in your workflow, then you can install wp-cli that offers a set of commands for export a dump of your DB, and also has another set of tools to make string replacement (such as domain changes. ie: replace the dev.domain.ext to www.domain.ext) in the DB. Of course you are not limited to use the wp-cli only in combination with CI / CD but it can also be used using this way of deployment. More specific : http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/export/ and http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/

Comment: Just export the database from the dev install(minus the wp-options table so long as you're not making changes to it) and then overwrite the production database.

Comment: @APAD1 this cannot work if he has images into the content of the posts that pointing the old domain. The best solution is to also apply a replacement of the domain in the contents, but this can be too complex if he has a large database. In addition, if he applies the replacement his self, then he should apply a fix to serialized data, because, the theme developer or a plugin develop, can write serialized data, that contains information mixed with the current site URL in the meta tables. This will have as a result damaged serialized data and his production site will probably brake.

Comment: @APAD1 this is the reason I suggested the `wp-cli` as a solution, as it provides all of those tools in a single tool with few commands to run.

Comment: `this cannot work if he has images into the content of the posts that pointing the old domain` All you have to do is resave permalinks to fix that. This is the method I use, works fine.

Comment: Sometimes in the body of a post, you have image tags like that: `<img src="http://www.domain.ext/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image.jpg" />`. This kind of information it is permanent into the DB and it is not related to the rewrite rules. Also, there are plugins, saving data into the `{prefix_}*meta` tables, using absolute URLs. Again this data are permanent in the DB and they are not related to the rewrite rules of the site. This will have as an effect if the dev site it turned off or it has a downtime, the images of the production site to not be available. [...]

Comment: [...] This, can have as a side effect the affection of the site speed optimization, as well will break the site contents.

Comment: @MerianosNikos wp-cli looks promising. Any thoughts on the particular command(s) I should be focusing on to get me this end result? Thanks for the input, also!

Comment: @ThomasStringer You should just have installed the `wp-cli` as a global command ( installation like the one you do in composer ), or at least have it in the root directory of your WordPress installation. Then from your root directory you are free to execute the commands. This way, will auto-find the required information for access the DB :). Of course, don't try to use the tool directly in dev and production. Try to use it first in local environment ;) :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos yeah that I understand, but there is an [exhaustive list of commands in wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/commands/), and I was just looking for a few pointers on which commands would give me the capability to move dev->prod in the database. I'm guessing `export` and `import`? I'm unfamiliar with WXR files.

Comment: @ThomasStringer exactly, export, import and search/replace. It's important to make a search and replace of the old / new domain, for the reasons I explain above.

Comment: @MerianosNikos perfect, thanks! Please feel free to make this information into an answer so I can upvote and accept :-)

Comment: Thank you @ThomasStringer :)

Comment: @ThomasStringer answer is done :) if you like to check it as the one that solved your problem and rate up, will be very nice :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have CI/CD in your workflow, then you can install wp-cli that offers a set of commands for export a dump of your DB, and also has another set of tools to make string replacement (such as domain changes. ie: replace the dev.domain.ext to www.domain.ext) in the DB. Of course, you are not limited to use the wp-cli only in combination with CI / CD but it can also be used using this way of deployment. More specific: [Export](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/export), [Import](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/), [Search & Replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace).